# Ajax "deselects" hyperlink under the mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a page that performs an Ajax request that replaces a div every second.
This div also has hyperlinks in it.

If the user tries to click one of the hyperlinks, it will work, but if they move the cursor over the link, wait for a second without moving the cursor, the hyperlink no longer has the "hover" pseudostyle and if they click at the wrong time, the link doesn't work.

Is there a way to update the div without causing this, or to restore the "mouse over" state of the link?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best bet would be to just update the link(s) individually, instead of destroying and recreating the full container div. This should eliminate the "flicker" which is causing the link to behave that way.

Comment: The div contains other items that need updating, and the href isn't the only thing that can change for the links, sometimes the style or content changes.

Comment: @thealliedhacker: Yes, you should still be able to change the style, innerHTML, etc, without causing the flicker. As for the other elements in the div, I suggest updating them individually as well. I do not think there is an easy workaround to the problem you are having, when dropping and re-create a whole div. It looks like browsers react to the "hover" pseudo-style only on a mouseMove event... and since it is not moving when you re-create the link, it does not behave as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Usability wise it sounds like a bad idea to update a div with links the user is supposed to be able to click... If the content is not actually changed with each refresh (just re-rendered by replacing it with the same content) it will not only flicker needlessly but it may cause the links to malfunction as you've noticed.

You could fix that by (somehow) comparing the old and new content of the div and do nothing if the content hasn't changed, but when it does change it would be quite confusing for the user if it changes just before they click. If you need to update the links with different content I'd suggest you implement some kind of animation (on actual change) like a fade-out+fade in or something, that would notify the user that the link they're aiming for is about to disappear. (I'd suggest a really slow fade-out (1-2 seconds) of the old content, and a quite fast fade in (50-200 ms maybe).

About hover style not working without moving the mouse; I really don't think you can do something about that, because that's browser behaviour. Moving the element using js or other fancy tricks, may or may not work and is probably not worth the effort. And if you only update the content when it has actually changed the link may not allways be in the same spot anyway...